# Wordpress. Вывод на главную страницу информации из разных рубрик

Tags: wordpress, вывод, запись

Задача состоит в том, чтобы вывести записи из рубрики FAQ в секцию разметки с вопросами, а из рубрики blog - соответственно в секцию блога. Все это на главной странице сайта. Тема своя, шаблона category.php нет. Есть index.php в котором пишу следующе:

```
    <section class="faq">
  <h2 class="faq__title">Частые вопросы</h2>
  <ul class="faq__questions">
  <?php
      global $post;

      $myposts = get_posts([ 
        'numberposts' => 4,
        'category-name'=> 'faq'            
      ]);

      if( $myposts ){
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
          setup_postdata( $post );
          ?>              
            <li class="question faq__question" style="background-image: url(<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/assets/img/quastion-icon.svg)">
              <h3 class="question__title"><?php the_title( ); ?></h3>
              <div class="question__text question__text_hidden">
                <?php the_field('faq_text'); ?>
              </div>
              <button type="button" class="question__arrow-down"></button>
            </li>        
          <?php 
        }
      } else {
        // Постов не найдено
      }
      wp_reset_postdata(); // Сбрасываем $post
    ?>        
  </ul>
</section>
<section class="blog" id="blog">
  <h2 class="blog__title">Блог</h2>
  <div class="tag-line blog__tag-line">
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">личностный рост</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">генные ключи</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">Тень</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">хологенетический профиль</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">Дар</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">Таро</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">коучинг</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">достигать цели</a>
    <a href="#" class="tag-line__tag">психология</a>
  </div>
  <div class="posts blog__posts">
  <?php
      global $post;

      $myposts = get_posts([ 
        'numberposts' => 10, 
        'category-name'=> 'blog'                    
        ]);

      if( $myposts ){
        foreach( $myposts as $post ){
          setup_postdata( $post );
          ?>              
            <a class="posts__post" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
            
            <p class="posts__title"><?php the_title() ?></p>
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
            </a>              
          <?php 
        }
      } else {
        // Постов не найдено
      }
      wp_reset_postdata(); // Сбрасываем $post
    ?>        
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn_dark blog__button" type="button">Показать ещё </button>
</section>
```

Проблема в том, что игнорируется разделение на рубрики и в faq и в blog выводятся все записи без разбора, не игнорируется только количество записей.

Буду рада любой подсказке.
P.S: в wordpress недавно, только разбираюсь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто!
не тире **category-name**, а подчёркивание **category_name** )))

А ещё как вариант, предлагаю обращаться к 'category' => по ID,